# asio::read with timeout

Tags: c++, boost, timeout, serial-port, boost-asio

I need to know how to read (sync or async doesn't matters) with a timeout. I want to check if a device is connected with a serial port or not.

For that I use `asio::write` and then I wait for the response of the device.

If a device is connected `asio::read(serial, boost::asio::buffer(&r,1))` works fine but if there is no device the program stops, which is is why I need the timeout

I know that I need a `deadline_timer` but I have no idea how to use it in the `async_read` function.

An example of how it works would be really helpful.

I know that there are many similar threads and I read lot of them but I can't find a solution that helps me solving my problem!

Answer (score 14):

The [code posted by Igor R.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144834/487356) did not compile for me. Here is my improved version of his code, which works perfectly. It uses lambdas to get rid of the `set_result` helper function.

```
template <typename SyncReadStream, typename MutableBufferSequence>
void readWithTimeout(SyncReadStream& s, const MutableBufferSequence& buffers, const boost::asio::deadline_timer::duration_type& expiry_time)
{
    boost::optional<boost::system::error_code> timer_result;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(s.get_io_service());
    timer.expires_from_now(expiry_time);
    timer.async_wait([&timer_result] (const boost::system::error_code& error) { timer_result.reset(error); });

    boost::optional<boost::system::error_code> read_result;
    boost::asio::async_read(s, buffers, [&read_result] (const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t) { read_result.reset(error); });

    s.get_io_service().reset();
    while (s.get_io_service().run_one())
    { 
        if (read_result)
            timer.cancel();
        else if (timer_result)
            s.cancel();
    }

    if (*read_result)
        throw boost::system::system_error(*read_result);
}
```

Comment: This works excellent to simulate a timeout for `boost::asio::async_read`. Really simple & solid approach to the problem. I like this simple technique & I want to adapt it for `boost::asio::async_write` case ? But it doesn't seem to work for the write case. Would you mind taking a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378022/how-to-do-a-boostasioasync-write-with-timeout) ?

Comment: [This example](http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2012/12/13/boost-c-read-from-serial-port-with-timeout-example/) is similar but does not use lambdas and is not templated.

Comment: Still we don't have any solution from boost for read with timeout?

Comment: `s.get_io_service().reset()` and `s.get_io_service().run_one()` do not work as `io_service` has been replaced by `io_context`, but I still can't figure out how to adapt the code. Any ideas?

Comment: I've successfully implemented the above solution in my code but, as stated below by @Tom Quarendon [in @Igor R. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144834/487356), I needed to added a `break` after cancelling the timer (Boost version: 1.69.0)

Comment: show its usage...

Comment: no, this does not work correctly with serial ports, function async_read will block if no data is available to read, there is no way to fix that, other to make sure you are not calling it when data is not available, or rewrite the io_service

Answer (score 7):

Once upon a time, the library author proposed the following way [to read synchronously with timeout](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/04/120339.php) (this example involves `tcp::socket`, but you can use serial port instead):

```
  void set_result(optional<error_code>* a, error_code b) 
  { 
    a->reset(b); 
  } 


  template <typename MutableBufferSequence> 
  void read_with_timeout(tcp::socket& sock, 
      const MutableBufferSequence& buffers) 
  { 
    optional<error_code> timer_result; 
    deadline_timer timer(sock.io_service()); 
    timer.expires_from_now(seconds(1)); 
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(set_result, &timer_result, _1)); 


    optional<error_code> read_result; 
    async_read(sock, buffers, 
        boost::bind(set_result, &read_result, _1)); 

    sock.io_service().reset(); 
    while (sock.io_service().run_one()) 
    { 
      if (read_result) 
        timer.cancel(); 
      else if (timer_result) 
        sock.cancel(); 
    } 


    if (*read_result) 
      throw system_error(*read_result); 
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the technique. Maybe this works in a single threaded scenario when there's no other async operations that might be going on.  What makes the while loop terminate? If there are other threads around, is calling io_service.reset() a safe thing to do?

Comment: @Tom Quarendon I guess you're right, it won't work if multiple threads are running the io_service. Note however that one can use io_service-per-core model, where there's one thread per io_service.

Comment: @Iror R. Having tried this out with a test multithreaded server, it *appears* to work. I had to add a "break" in the "if" and "else if" in order to make the loop terminate though. What I don't know is whether this is "supposed" to work in this multithreaded environment

Comment: Actually, scrub that. I can't get a version that works OK in all cases, single and multithreaded, with other traffic going on and without.

Comment: these examples are honestly so frustrating because they show neither the includes or the namespaces

Comment: @basil this is not a self-containing example, it requires some understanding of the context we're talking of.

Answer (score 6):

You don't use `deadline_timer` in `async_read`. But you can start two async processes:

1. An `async_read` process on serial port. [boost::asio::serial_port](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html) has a [cancel](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_serial_port/cancel.html) method that cancels all async operations on it.
2. A deadline timer with required timeout. In completion handler for `deadline_timer` you can `cancel` the serial port. This should close the `async_read` operation and call its completion handler with an error.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

class timed_connection
{
    public:
        timed_connection( int timeout ) :
            timer_( io_service_, boost::posix_time::seconds( timeout ) ),
            serial_port_( io_service_ )
        {
        }

        void start()
        {
              timer_.async_wait
                (
                 boost::bind
                 (
                  &timed_connection::stop, this
                 )
                );

            // Connect socket
            // Write to socket

            // async read from serial port
            boost::asio::async_read
                (
                 serial_port_, boost::asio::buffer( buffer_ ),
                 boost::bind
                 (
                  &timed_connection::handle_read, this,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error
                 )
                );

            io_service_.run();
        }

    private:
        void stop()
        {  
            serial_port_.cancel();
        }

        void handle_read ( const boost::system::error_code& ec)
        {  
            if( ec )
            {  
                // handle error
            }
            else
            {  
                // do something
            }
        }

    private:
        boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
        boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
        boost::asio::serial_port serial_port_;
        boost::array< char, 8192 > buffer_;
};

int main()
{
    timed_connection conn( 5 );
    conn.start();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question **explicitly** states that he uses a serial device, not a TCP endpoint. UNIX sockets might be an option if he used *nix, but the OS isn't stated and they kind of break portability.

Comment: @TC1, Sure, edited the code. Conceptually the way Asio abstracts it, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one or *easy* answer per se, since even if you do an async read, the callback never gets called and you now have a loose thread somewhere around.

You're right in assuming that `deadline_timer` is one of the possible solutions, but it takes some fiddling and shared state. There's the [blocking TCP example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp), but that's for `async_connect` and there's a cool thing about it returning when it has nothing to do. `read` won't do that, worst case scenario -- it'll crash & burn 'cause of the invalid resource. So the `deadline timer` thing is one of your options, but there's actually an easier one, that goes somewhat like this:

```
boost::thread *newthread = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&::try_read));
if (!newthread->timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(5))) {
    newthread->interrupt();
}
```

Basically, do the read in another thread and kill it off if it times out. You should read up on [Boost.Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread.html).

If you interrupt it, make sure the resources are all closed.

Comment: Are you sure that asio i/o operation is an interruption point?

Comment: Has anyone been able to confirm this? Does this solution work?

Comment: i have tested this, did not work for me. interrupt will not halt the thread during asio i/o operation.

Comment: Did not work for me either (tested with `boost::thread::timed_join()`: the thread is not halted).